# Is there a term for an "unbounded simplex"?

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, polyhedra

Is there a general term for regions like $\{(x,y):x>y\}$ and $\{(x,y,z): x>y>z\}$, i.e., regions which are simplexes with one open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for an [unbounded polytope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope#Intersection_of_half-spaces)?

Comment: In my optimization class, we just said "polyhedron" (a polytope being a bounded polyhedron).

Answer (score 1):

I was somehow brought up with the term "polytopal cone", but it doesn't seem to be standard at all.

I dislike "polyhedra" because to me, those are just $3$-dimensional polytopes.